# Seagate Ext Drive 2TB now shows empty, all data is now listed ubder Seagate Ext Drive (1)

Tags: 14.04, external-hdd

Seagate Ext Drive 2TB now shows empty, all data is now listed under Seagate Ext Drive (1). I can live with this but would like to get back to normal, ie all data contained in one drive, the original Seagate External Drive.
Just before I do something silly, can someone tell me what I SHOULD do?

Answer (score 0):

it appears that you have it mounted twice. Hence the "(1)". If the drive is just used for storage, and does not have your user profile stored on it (some people do this to reduce writes for sold state drive builds) you can eject both of them, and re-mount the drive. using `sudo mount /dev/sdb /home/user/external ntfs` where sdb is your drive, and /home/username/external is where you want it mounted and the name to mount with. if you leave this blank, it should mount with the drive volume's name (set when it was formatted).

Comment: Just a heads-up, the reason you are getting the `no such file` error is because of spaces. They are considered seperators in Bash. To deal with them (and use them as spaces), either `"escape the entire path using quote marks"` or just `escape\ only\ the\ spaces\ with\ backslashes\`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up Whaaaaaat, I had forgotten this little tweak! I can now access Seagate Expansion Drive1 but not the other one (without 1), root owned.

Comment: Getting in a mess with this, could use some help please. Output from blkid is

Comment: ray@ray-Aspire-5735:~$ blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="794075a0-22bc-4df9-b65d-f3544ac7dbc2" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="4ea9d419-715b-4640-a783-7fd1439c9b8f" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="Seagate Expansion Drive" UUID="5A22DB2D22DB0CBF" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdd1: UUID="1768-274C" TYPE="vfat" 
Apologies, I forgot that 'Enter' terminates the comment

Comment: Output from ray@ray-Aspire-5735:/media/ray$ ls    1762-274C  1768-274C  Seagate Expansion Drive  Seagate Expansion Drive1
So, as well as two Seagate drives I now have two 1768-274Cs, which , to clarify is an 8.5GB MP4 player